# Zsh file to add username and machine name?

Tags: oh-my-zsh

I've been looking up how to add username and machine name to my iterm2 terminal. However, what I came across is a bit confusing...

Here's what I wanted it to be:

[image]

So I open my ~/.zshrc and then add this code at the end of the file like this?

```
PROMPT="$fg[magenta]%}$USER@%{$fg[yellow]%}%m ${PROMPT}"
```

and what should I add before this code?

```
# Which words?
```

If this are not the correct steps, then what are the correct steps I need to take to add the name and machine name?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a recursive reference, which ensures the prompt will be written twice.

Remove:

> ${PROMPT}

this won't fix your color problem but it will fix if you are seeing double user written out.